# Error accessing COM components

Tags: c#, com, ms-word, office-2007

I built an add-in for Microsoft Office Word. There isn't an issue using the add-in when Word is ran as Administrator, but when it's not ran as an Administrator, there are two common exceptions accessing Ribbon elements.

The first Exception:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonUI'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000C03A7-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error:  could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030002 (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND)).
   at Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl(String ControlID)
```

This error occurs when the Control is invalidated by the following code:

```
ribbon.InvalidateControl("control-id");
```

And the second Exception:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error:  could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030002 (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND)).
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.get_Selection()
```

This error occurs on the last line of the following code:

```
object wdStory = Word.WdUnits.wdStory;
object wdMove = Word.WdMovementType.wdMove;
WrdApp.Selection.EndKey(ref wdStory, ref wdMove)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does it work on other computers? I broke the registry the other day (on a coworkers computer no less) and was experiencing issues similar to this will all programs that used COM components.  If it works on another computer, I'll explain what I did to fix it.

Comment: Yes, works in development computer. Only in the test machine is not working. Maybe because I install (and unistall) many versions of Office (2007, 2007-64, 2010, 2010-64)

Comment: Oh dear.  Well, what operating system is the test machine running?

Comment: Windows 7 64bits with Office 2007 32bits

Comment: But why when I'm running as administrator everything works fine?

Comment: I don't know, but I had the same issue.  Running programs as an administrator worked, but most would encounter errors and crash otherwise.  I'll post an answer with what I did.

Comment: I removed my answer because it didn't work for you, and we don't need people going and blowing up their registries by trying risky solutions like this.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Problem solved!

I have previously installed Office 2010, so there are some inconsistences in Windows Registry.
To fix them, open the `regedit` and find for the CLSID from the error.

You will find something like that for the second error:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

With the subkeys:

- ProxyStubClsid
- ProxyStubClsid32
- TypeLib

Take a look at the `(Default)` and `Version` values inside of `TypeLib`.

Now find the node below, using the `(Default)` value as `<TypeLib ID>`.

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\<TypeLib ID>\<version>`

As child of this elements you will find more than one element, one of then is the `Version` of the first registry. If you inspect the others elements, you will find that they point to nothing. **Remove the others!!!** It's solved!

Comment: @Wug, problem found! Thanks for help me.

Comment: Had the same problem when rolling back from Office 2013 to Office 2010. This solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks so much! Spent all day debugging an add-in on one persons computer and this solved it

Answer (score 8):

I started getting the same exception after upgrading to the latest Office version. I tried a number of suggested fixes including cleaning up the registry in a way similar to what @Victor described.

What eventually helped (even though it might have been a combination of factors) was 'repairing' the installation:

<kbd>Programs and Features</kbd> → latest <kbd>Office</kbd> version → <kbd>Repair</kbd>.

Comment: This worked for me also with Office 365 and Windows 7. Thank you!

Comment: Works for me, I have only VS2010 and Office 2016

Comment: This worked for me using VS2017 and O365. 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The office repair worked for me. In my case I had installed Project which I believe altered the config and was unable to call up a procedure to migrate data from an excel workbook to SQL

Answer (score 0):

Just install Office 2010 / MS word / .NET Programmability Support.

Answer (score 0):

@Victor You got me headed on the right path. My issue was not multiple values in the registry but rather, a missing value that Office365 never added. Thanks to you I was able to find my own resolution. A thousand thousand thanks.

[Details are here for anyone still looking for a resolution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782002/solved-outlook-com-not-registered)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today with VS2015 and Office 2013. Changing the Platform target to x64 worked for me.