# Class not registered error when creating Excel workbook in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

When I try to access an Excel spreadsheet using the following code I get a "Library not registered' error when defining the workbook object wrkbuk using C# from Visual Studio 2012 with Office 2007 (ver 12) installed

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        string bookname = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RECRUITMENT & SELECTION\MOVEMENTS\MOVEMENTS\Miscellaneous Documents\VacanciesREAL.xls";
        Workbook wrkbuk = excapp.Workbooks.Open(bookname); 
        Worksheet wrksht = new Worksheet();
```

The error details are

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled   HResult=-2147467262
>   Message=Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
>   following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).   Source=mscorlib

I've created a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll in  the Office 14 Primary Interop Assembly that comes with VS 2012 and also for the Office 12 version of the dll and neither fixes the problem. I've tried registering the dlls with regasm but this does not help either.

I can create the worksheet wrksht on the following line OK with the Office 14 and Office 12 dlls so the problem seems only affect workbook definition.

**Dec 17 2013**

Tried reinstalling Office 2007 to no avail but found this solution, which worked. It was at

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3f92da7-96d3-404b-89d0-d236800ceae5/vs-2012-rc-and-visual-studio-tools-for-office?forum=vsto

Problem is code from multiple versions of Office - I had code from Office 14, possibly coming from VS 2012 install

I suspect that VS 2012 RC has installed the Office 2013 type libraries, and that there are now duplicate versions registered. I got that specific error message

> ('unable to cast
>   _Application'....'TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED')

after a messy uninstall, and then re-installing an older version of Office. I solved it by following the advice of another forum thread here which I'm sadly unable to find...basically I searched the registry for the CLSID in the error message, so, `{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`. Its registry key contained two keys, one of which was called 'TypeLib', which in turn contained another CLSID for the type library. I then searched the registry, starting at the beginning again, for that second CLSID, which led me to the relevant interop type library. It had two entries....8.3 and 8.4, the bigger number corresponding to the later version of Office....which I deleted...and immediately was able to run my program.

Comment: The registry on that machine is damaged and is missing a key.  Reinstall Office to fix this.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) (or a wrapper like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)). That way you could create Excel Documents without the need to have Office installed on the machine.

Comment: Edited post to provide solution

Comment: I reproduced the problem on 3 different machines and all of them were related to installing office components with different versions. The solution described by SimonKravis (regedit) is working correctly for me, and I believe it can be extended for most similar exceptions with MsOffice Interop Tools.

Comment: This happened to me after installing Project 2013 while keeping Office 2010 for all the other Office applications. Had an addin that was developed for Outlook 2010 and was working just fine before installing Project. Installing Project broke the addin. Stuzor's Registry Edit solution below fixed it.

Comment: @SimonKravis Please provide your solution in an Answer and then mark that answer as correct using the green check mark. This closes out the QA and helps other people find the answer. It's okay to answer your own question.

Comment: Had this exact same issue when trying to create a Word.Application using Powershell.  Fix was just as you described except my versions were 8.6 and 8.7 (and I removed 8.7)

Comment: Thanks! You second solution is worked for me! Excel  run fine now. (Delete second unused key in {00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}).

Answer (score 40):

I had this exact same problem. Here's how I fixed it:

Go to

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\` and search for `Office.Interop.Excel`.

I found `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\(guid)\1.8` but its **child nodes were empty!** **I deleted it** because Office 15 wasn't installed on that machine, and hey presto - it worked.

Either our VSTO project installer, or our own custom installer must have placed the 1.8 folder there.

I found the solution here:

[Error accessing COM components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957595/error-accessing-com-components)

Comment: If you removed Office 2016, want to keep 2013 , and the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\(guid)\1.9 key has no children, then delete the 1.9 folder.

Comment: Thanks. Are the number related to the version of Office? I.e. 1.6 = 2007, 1.7 = 2010 1.8 = 2013 and so on?

Comment: @hims056, yes the folder numbers relate to the office version numbers.

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same issue. If you have installed a new version of Office and for some reason you have to install the older version without removing the new one (For my case I just need to install the Office XP Photo Editor) and this caused the issue.

After spending 3 hours up and down, the best way is to repair the new version of Office and everything was back to normal as it should be.

Hope this info helps provided you have the same or similar scenario.

Comment: With office 365 (or others), try the repair option, it will regenerate the keys.  This fixed my issue.

Comment: I tried the solution with the registery, but it didn't work. I use the office repair tool and work.

Answer (score 8):

Something which hasn't been mentioned here but which may be useful is that subkeys of 1.XX can cause issues as well. For example:
Under **Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}** I had the subkey **1.9**. This in turn has the subkey **0**(or should). Now under this, there were **two** subkeys - **Win32** and **Win64**. As a result, Visual Studio was unable to resolve the location of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll - it was reading two subkeys where it could only read one. **Deleting the Win32 subkey fixed my issue completely.** Please note that this was done after a complete reinstall of VS 2017 & Office 365 Pro Plus. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks this has been driving me crazy for the last hour! I think it's because I have Office 2013 but our company recently pushed the latest version of Skype for Business which I'm assuming is part of Office 2016.

Answer (score 6):

I will confirm @stuzor 's answer on two machines I've encountered.

### Background:

```
Windows7 64 bit
Office 2010 (32bit) 
Lync 2013
```

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\  , searched for "Office.Interop.Excel". Found the barely existent "1.8" folder. Upon deletion, the function in an old VB.net app began working immediately.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer if you can not modify or delete the regedit records. I had the same problem, in the company where I work, there are about 30 machines with office 2010 and I could not erase or open records in the regedit. because the client machine was in a domain that would not let me. although I had administrator permissions it did not allow me to delete records in the regedit. I tried to find a solution for 1 month, and I did not find it. so I had to stop using interop and migrate to OpenXml to edit excel templates and ClosedXml to create new excel. This saved my life, because my boss was already pressing me.

Open the project/solution in Visual Studio, and open the console using the Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console command. 
and install 2 packages

1. Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml -Version 2.5.0
2. Install-Package SpreadsheetLight

pd: OpenXml  2.8  dont work with SpreadsheetLight, better use 2.5.0

add this in the beggining

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using SpreadsheetLight;
```

in your  button or class copy and modify

```
    SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
    fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
    if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        SLDocument sl = new SLDocument("c:\\bin\\est1.xlsx", "Sheet1");

        sl.SetCellValue("E9", "Let's party!!!!111!!!1");

        sl.SelectWorksheet("Sheet2");
        sl.SetCellValue("C7", "Before anyone calls the popo!");

        sl.AddWorksheet("ERTRT");
        sl.SetCellValue("B4", "Who let the dogs out?");
        sl.SetCellValue("B5", "Woof!");

        sl.SaveAs(fichero.FileName);    

        MessageBox.Show("Report " + fichero.FileName + "!");
    }
```

Comment: Very-very different approach to the problem, but eventually solves it.

Answer (score 1):

The registry hack described above fixed the same problem for me. The only difference was I had a 1.9 
and a 1.7 entry. I deleted the 1.9 key and my problem was fixed.

Other info:

OS: Windows 10

Visual Studio Professional 2015

C# Windows Form Application

This was on my work laptop. We have Office 2010 installed on each workstation.

**Some other things I tried that DID NOT WORK were the following:**

Repairing MS OFFICE

Reinstalling MS OFFICE

Downloading Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies from Microsoft.

I also had several versions of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll on my laptop. Deleting previous versions did not fix the problem.

**Glad I went to STACKOVERFLOW.COM because this place ROCKS!!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem.

Our setup is like this :
Office 2010 : Word and Excel
but 
Office 2013 : Outlook

We ran the installation program for Office 2010 and **choose the repair option.**
After that, all the wrong keys in the registry for Word and Excel were deleted and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem... The code that was previously running, started throwing the same exception when a new Application instance was created. To fix this:

> 1. **Programs and Features**, did an order by date installed and could see there were some Microsoft Office 365 updates from the same day the
>      code had stopped working.
> 2. For both **Microsoft Office 365 -en-us** and **Microsoft Office 365 Pro Plus -en-us**, right click **Change** and select **Quick Fix**

Tried to run my solution and it was working again.