# Error while trying to create an excel file in C#

Tags: c#, excel, windows-mobile-6.5

Good morning,
I'm trying to create Excel file in C#, I looked to the way to do it, and I found a tutorial, here is the code I tried:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;  
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook worKbooK;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet;  
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range celLrangE;

        excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excel.Visible = false;
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Well, I have this error on initializing the variable `excel`

```
COM object with CLSID '{00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' cannot be created due to the following error: Class not registered .
```

I searched for this error, what I found is solution to problems in cases, but none has the problem in Excel operations, so ... ?

PS: I'm creating an application for Windows Mobile 6.5, but I think it's supposed to work on it, if it works of course.

**For the vote down hungers**, well ... unleash yourselves, I can't stop you :) but believe me, I tried a lot, there's so many ways to create Excel files, but whatever I try, the same error is summoning, I think it's not the problem of library, or code, but something else I can't find.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Just curious, but what "bit-ness" of Microsoft Office do you have installed?  32-bit or 64-bit?  Also, I feel a bit silly for asking, but have you tried running Excel on the computer?  Does it work?

Comment: Is that matters? because I use the application on the phone, when I press button (which has the press event, the code above), the error comes on the line of `excel = .... `,  I'm using a Windows 7 64 bits with MS Visual Studio 2008, the phone is on Windows Mobile 6.5

Comment: So, your code is attempting to interop with Microsoft Excel. Unless Microsoft Excel is installed and working on your device, how will your program inter-operate with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class not registered error when creating Excel workbook in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397506/class-not-registered-error-when-creating-excel-workbook-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Ah, you mean on the device? of course excel is installed on it, and works very well

Comment: @Thalles Noce, my application is running on a mobile device, I've found this topic, but it doesn't match to my case :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975105/80040154-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult

Comment: @OldProgrammer,  I repeat, the application is running on a mobile device ! Even the reference (library on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12`) is a x86, which I suppose corresponding the the office on the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use another Library: https://code.google.com/archive/p/excellibrary/

Found in this question: [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this code works, but the file can't be opened, I tried the "open and repair", but it doesn't work too, I'm using Office 2013, But when I tried to open it with Office 2007 "Want you to read the file anyway" and it was opened, is there a way to create a normal correct file format?
Anyway, thank you