# C# Program that uses excel throwing exception TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, vsto

So I made a program that read some cells from an Excel file (.xlsx) and then do an online search with the data.

It is working fine on my computer (Windows 8.1, Visual Studio Community 2013, Office 2013) but when I send it to a friend on another machine (Windows 8.1, no Visual Studio, Office 2010) the program shows an error message saying (bad translation from portuguese):

> System.InvalidCastException: It is not possible to convert the COM
>   object of  type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' on
>   interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on component COM for
>   the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed
>   due to the following error: Error when loading the library/DLL of
>   type. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

in

> System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr
>   pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)    in
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass.get_Workbooks()    in
>   ConsultaProcessos.MainForm.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    in
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    in
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    in
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    in
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    in
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    in
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    in
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

I asked him to instal VSTO 2010 and .NET Framework 4.5 but the error still happens.

My project has Excel 15.0 and Office 15.0 and VSTO 2010 added to the references.

Is there anything else that might be done for this to work?
Thanks in advance!

*see below for some of the code*

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;

Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

//These two lines do the magic.
xlWorkSheet.Columns.ClearFormats();
xlWorkSheet.Rows.ClearFormats();

iTotalColumns = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
iTotalRows = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
```

**EDIT:**
I tried running in another computer with Office 2010 and it worked. It is not working on a particular PC with office 2010.
I will see if the Registry fix suggested by Technovation will fix this.

Comment: Does he have the same version/edition of Excel?

Comment: No, as described on my question, my office package is 2013 and his is 2010

Comment: this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957595/error-accessing-com-components did not help?

Comment: I will try this regedit fix asap. Was away from my pc for a while.

Answer (score 0):

> my office package is 2013 and his is 2010

First of all, make sure that you use properties and methods that exists in the oldest Office version. You will get an exception trying to call non-existing method or property. I'd suggest embedding interop types into the assembly setting the *Embed interop types* property of the PIAs to true (available in .net 4.0 and later).

Does the target PC(problematic one) have the Click2Run edition of MS Office installed?

The fact is that the Click2Run edition of Office 2010 doesn't support automation. Click2Run apps have no automation interface and cannot be automated. See [Office 2010 Click-to-Run compatibility with add-ins](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982431) for more information. It states:

> Out-of-process add-ins/applications are stand-alone programs, scripts, or applications that use Office object model APIs to start functionality in the application and integrate with Office. In this case, the out-of-process application drives Office. Out-of-process applications are not supported in Click-to-Run.

Also see the [0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ac50fa41-8d47-4fa9-81a3-914f262676af/0x80029c4a-typeecantloadlibrary?forum=vsto) similar forum thread.

Comment: I just tried running the program on another computer with office 2010 and it worked... I will try your other suggestions as well as the registry idea that Technovation gave and will report back soon.