# Unable to open mailItem because of outlook interface..!

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, office-2013

I have an application where i create a mailItem using Outlook interop. 
On some systems the code works without problems.

But on one of the systems this error appears:

> Message= Unable to cast COM object of type 
>       'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 
>       'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed because 
>       the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 
>       '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed
>
> due to the following error: Interface not registered

I think it has something to do with the register see: [Answer on Error accesing COM components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957595/error-accessing-com-components)

But i need to solve this problem in the code, because i can't acces all the systems with this kind of problem.

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

//Create email body with the customers
string mailBody = customers;
//Create the email with the settings
Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.Subject = mailSubject;
mailItem.Attachments.Add(totalPath);
mailItem.Body = mailBody;
mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
try
{
    //Try to open outlook, set message if its not possible to open outlook
    mailItem.Display(true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

How can i solve this in my code?

P.S. Every system uses the office 2013 version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following code instead:

```
 oApp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application")) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
```

It looks like something is wrong with the windows registry records. Take a look at the similar forum thread - [Error: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39773b51-6a08-4753-ab45-4fe748c2ca2d/error-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoftofficeinteropoutlookapplicationclass-to?forum=outlookdev).

Do you have the Click2Run edition of Office installed on the PC? See [How to: Verify Whether Outlook Is a Click-to-Run Application on a Computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864733.aspx) for more information.