# Python win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch fails if program is compiled with py2exe

Tags: python, com, py2exe

I am trying tot compile a Python 3.3 program that uses COM to interact with MS Word.
The interpreted version of the program runs OK and brings up MS word.

```
word =win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(u"Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Add()
word.Visible = True
```

Running makepy for Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library(8.5) gives me the reference key 00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046.

Now when the program is compiled with py2exe, the compiled program dies saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
File "C:\Python 3.3.5\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 544, in EnsureDispatch
    disp_class = CLSIDToClass.GetClass(str(disp_clsid))
File "C:\Python 3.3.5\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\CLSIDToClass.py", line 46, in GetClass
    return mapCLSIDToClass[clsid] KeyError: '{00020970-0000-0000-000-000000000046}'
```

Now what is interesting is that the key this error gives to me is different from the key makepy finds. Searching the internet I found as a possible solution that the registry is messed up. That however would explain a failure from BOTH situations (i.e. interpreted AND compiled) whereas my problem is restricted to the compiled version. I also wondered whether there might be a 32/64bit problem but my python toolchain in 32 bit as far as I know. I have tried:

- py2exe setup scripts with and without typelibs as py2exe options
- cleaning up genpy (in both the temp dir and the python sitepackages
  win32com client dir)

I look forward to your advise on this one.

Comment: maybe related: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/UsingEnsureDispatch

Comment: I guess with late binding, `win32com.client` never queries that interface (`_Application`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error accessing COM components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957595/error-accessing-com-components)