# UIPATH - Send Outlook Mail (Unable to cast COM object)

Tags: outlook, uipath

I want to set up a robot able to send e-mails thank's to the UIPATH activity "Send Outlook Mail".
but a receive this error message :

> Send Outlook Mail Message: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Interface not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155).

[Some people on internet seem to have managed to correct this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957595/error-accessing-com-components) due to the versioning of Outlook. But my problem seems different because I only have the versions 8.7 listed in the IID : HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

Comment: Did you use the Click2Run edition of MS Office? What version do you have installed?

Comment: Yes I did, I have the  "Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise" version 2105 .

Answer (score 0):

It seems your windows registry records are messed. Try to "repair" your Microsoft Office installation. Go to `Programs and Features`, select `Modify` and then `Repair Online`.

This is a widely spread issue when dealing with COM libraries. Here is what the Error: [Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39773b51-6a08-4753-ab45-4fe748c2ca2d/error-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoftofficeinteropoutlookapplicationclass-to?forum=outlookdev) forum thread states:

Sounds like you have a problem with your typelib registration.  Presumably, the Com interop layer is hitting the registry to try to locate the typelib.  It would start by looking under HKCR\Interface{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\Typelib.  The default value should refer to the guid for the typelib that defines the interface in question: which should be located under the following key: HKCR\Typelib{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}.  There should be a version subkey and then a 0 subkey, and a win32 subkey under that.  The default value of the win32 key should point to the typelib (which is msoutl.olb).

I'd recommend checking your Office directory for msoutl.olb.  If it is there, try running 'regtlib msoutl.olb'.  You should have regtlib on your machine is part of your Visual Studio install, I believe.  Anyway, reregistering the typelib will rewrite all of the necessary keys to the registry.  You will need administrative privileges for this operation.

Also you may find the [Outlook issue - Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass'](https://support.boyum-it.com/hc/en-us/articles/206772337-Outlook-issue-Unable-to-cast-COM-object-of-type-Microsoft-Office-Interop-Outlook-ApplicationClass-) page helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eugene, I followed step by step your instructions. 
- I "repaired" my Microsoft Office installation. (actually it was reinstalled)
sadly I only have a default and version subkey in the IID you give me. (no win32 folder)
The issue is still the same

Comment: After uninstalling Office you could clean windows registry keys, so after installing anew you will get a clean installation. Do you get any problems with new machines?

Comment: Cleaning registery is often a good way to make more problems, I prefer avoid it. I can't check on another computer because UIPATH is only installed on my machine ...

Comment: I'm not sure if is it important or not but my error message is a bit different than the one in the link you linked me. 
- from your link : "failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL."
- my message : "failed due to the following error: Interface not registered"

Comment: Are you able to automate Outlook from other Office applications using VBA? Does your code work properly in that case?

Comment: I just check it from Excel using VBA and yes it work well this way .
https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-outlook/

Comment: Then the problem is with UIPATH.